# Qual è il significato di "tirare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Sulle notizie di [Euronews](http://it.euronews.com/2017/06/05/arabia-saudita-bahrein-emirati-ed-egitto-chiudono-le-frontiere-col-qatar) ho letto

> La mossa delle quattro nazioni arabe approfondisce ulteriormente la divisione tra i paesi del Golfo per il sostegno qatariota ai gruppi islamici. L’Arabia Saudita afferma che le truppe qatariote **sarebbero state tirate** dalla guerra in corso in Yemen.

Non capisco il significato del verbo "tirare" nella frase precedente. L'ho cercato in alcuni dizionari, ma appaiono tantissime accezioni che non riesco a vedere a quale corrisponda. Significa che l'Arabia Saudita accusa il Qatar di aver inviato truppe in Yemen? Oppure l'accusa sarebbe invece di aver ritirato le truppe qatariote della guerra in Yemen?

Comment: È un refuso del giornalista che intendeva dire ritirate ed invece ha scritto tirate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A me sembra che non abbia il minimo senso. Forse doveva essere *ritirate*, ma anche così non è spiegato sufficientemente bene che truppe siano e cosa abbiano a che fare con il resto della notizia.

E anche *approfondisce* è un verbo che non mi suona completamente appropriato in quella frase.

Forse è una cattiva traduzione da un'altra lingua.

Comment: Infatti la versione audio della notizia dice: "Doha è stata anche esclusa dalla coalizione militare a guida saudita che combatte nello Yemen".

Comment: Penso proprio sia una traduzione letterale dall'inglese. La frase "pulled from the war" è inglese idiomatico che significherebbe "rimosse/ritirate dalla guerra" ("pull" = "tirare").

Comment: @EuroMicelli: Curiosamente però la  [versione in inglese della notizia](http://www.euronews.com/2017/06/05/four-countries-cut-diplomatic-links-with-qatar/) non contiene questa frase.